# Two Azure SQL VM with SQL Server and Analysis Server installed on them, I want to access SSAS on one VM from another

Tags: azure-active-directory, ssas, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have two Azure SQL VM with SQL Server and Analysis Server installed on them, I want to access SSAS on one VM from another using an Authentication Mechanism which will allow me to use only one cred using SSMS to access it.

I am able to access SQL Server on these VMs using SQL Authentication, while for SSAS I ma having problem to understand how to give one windows user access on another machine.

While VM show they are in same VNET, while when I try to add another VM windows user to another it says unable to find.

Any leads

Comment: Are the VMs domain joined? If not do you have a common local username on both servers?

Comment: Have you opened port 2383 in the SSAS VM firewall?

Comment: @GregGalloway These machines are not domain joined, they have usernames like vm1\Ankit, vm2\Ankit

Answer (score 1):

You could specify whether **Windows Authentication** is used to connect to a SQL Server Analysis Services server. Also, Ensure that the account you are connecting with is a member of the Server Administrator role on another Azure VM. Before this, you need to add the two machines in the same AD domain. For more information, see [Grant server admin rights to an Analysis Services instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/grant-server-admin-rights-to-an-analysis-services-instance).

For more references, you could get the details about [connecting from client applications (Analysis Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/connect-from-client-applications-analysis-services#bkmk_SSMS).

Hope this could help you.

Comment: As you specified to add windows user as admin, we can do that only if two machines are in same AD domain because when you add one user which is not part of the domain where SSAS is, it will not be able to find the user. Right now what I trying is to add both machines in same AD Domain so that I can add windows user of one machine to another and access SSAS over it.

Comment: I think Nancy above comments says adding windows user as an admin on SSAS which is not complete answer we need to add the two machines in same domain, which I am working on will add complete answer once done. Thanks.